# pulling out from a text file and do some process in the minimal time Python

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I have a text file with a billion lines. In each line there is an integer.
I try to pull them out and to make some processing which takes some long time - so I need to push the items I read to a queue and make the process with the maximum threads that the CPU can handle. 
In addition, before the script starts, there is a user input which tells how much integers I want to read from the file in a 1 second. For example: if the user wants to read only 1000 lines(integers) per second, I want to do something like 
sleeping for (1/1000 second - this is for visulaizing a delay in reading from outer file disk). 
I tried to solve it through the next example I found here on one of the questions but with no success: 
(I work with pyscripter)

```
def worker():
while True:
    item = q.get()
    do_work(item)
    q.task_done()

q = Queue()
for i in range(num_worker_threads):
 t = Thread(target=worker)
 t.daemon = True
 t.start()

for item in source():
q.put(item)

q.join()       # block until all tasks are done
```

Comment: How do you want to read a file using threads? It won't speedup your harddrive if you open the file in multiple threads. And why do you want to display a billion integers to the user?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't explain it well. I'm a student, it's just homework. The printing of the integer is not realy a printing. It's something more compicated  which does some processing, so the processing can take some time which is bigger than the file reading. I call the printing - DoProcess().
I edited my post

Comment: I can't see a problem with your program, it works as expected. Although I didn't test if it is really faster than without threads.